# Do 9 speed and 11 speed derailleurs need different hangers?

Tags: derailleur-hanger

I just installed an 11 speed drivetrain on an On-one Lurcher. The swap-out drop outs are for 9mm axels, and probably 9 speed drive trains. The only problem I have is that with the B-screw backed out all the way I still have a 20mm gap between the derailleur pulley and the top cog, and considering the top cog has 50 teeth, that's a **huge** distance. The only thing I can figure is that the hanger is not compatible for the set up, and the only solution I can come up with to close that gap to 5 or 6mm is to file down the stop for the B-screw on the hanger.

Do 11 speed derailleurs need a different hanger than 9 speed derailleurs?

Comment: Something's weird there - do you have any photos to [edit] into your question ?   20mm outside of a dinner-plate-sized 50T suggests you have some kind of extender hanger too ?   Also please check the exact model of your rear derailleur to include, could be relevant.

Comment: You have the chain installed, correct?

Comment: @MaplePanda Chain is on yes.

Comment: @Criggle No extender hanger, it's all new Deore wide range stuff.

Answer (score 9):

Hangers are never speed-specific. Most of the time, a frame takes a given hanger and that's the only one, regardless of what derailleur and cassette are used.

The big gap you can't do anything about means you are almost certainly running into the main extant situation that creates the  "most of the time" qualifier above. That situation is when your frame has a direct-mount hanger and the derailleur you're installing either isn't compatible with that, or it is a compatible Shimano derailleur and the b-link hasn't been removed yet. Usually this situation comes up when a frame has a direct mount hanger installed and someone goes to put a Shimano mountain 12 or any SRAM drivetrain on it, which are never direct mount hanger compatible. (The cynical line on direct mount hangers is it was Shimano playing Microsoft; the charitable one is it's structurally better for the design of modern derailleurs.)

Here are some images from [Wheels Mfg](https://wheelsmfg.com/blog/standard-mount-vs-direct-mount-derailleur-hangers.html) that explain it:
[image]
[image]

Generally speaking if a frame has a direct mount hanger, there's always also a standard version.

If it's not the above, another way you could have gotten to such a wide gap even with the 50t is if you have one of the Shimano derailleurs where there are several notches near the mounting bolt that look like they could be the one that's supposed to rest against the hanger tab, but only one of them is. It's always the one that angles the derailleur up highest. If you do it any of the other ways, the cage angle gets dropped lower and more forward, and the gap will be too big. If this is what happened, be careful that if the chain length was set when it was low like this, it will be too short when it's angled right.

Comment: Shimano appear to have discontinued using "Direct Mount" so it can't have been that good.